# poor gallery scrolling performance when using a background image

Tags: android

I am currently using a modified Gallery widget that contains ImageView's.  The ImageView's have bitmap's with many transparent pixels.

If I set a background png image to an activity or window, the gallery is very choppy.  If I set a solid background color, it is silky smooth.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the calculations done with the transparent pixels on the gallery images.

I have tried removing the transparency layer on the background png and also tried an 8 bit png.

I have also tried changing the Window PixelFormat to RGB_565 and OPAQUE.

Lastly, I have tried making a proxy image xml for my background setting dithering to true and false.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the background image of my activity was scaling.  If the background image needed to be scaled in any kind of way, the gallery performance was horrible.  Once I made an image alias xml for my background and set it to not scale, the performance was good again.